# Why is 0 sometimes Numeric and sometimes not Numeric?

Tags: raku

Why is `0` sometimes Numeric and sometimes not Numeric?

```
my @numbers = -1, 0, 1, 'hello';
.say for @numbers.grep( Numeric );
say "====";
for @numbers -> $n {
    say $n if $n.Numeric;
}
```

---

```
#-1
#0
#1
#====
#-1
#1
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem is in your interpretation of `$n.Numeric`.  You appear to think that it returns a `Bool` to indicate whether something is `Numeric` (although your own example shows otherwise).

In any case, `$n.Numeric` **COERCES** to a `Numeric` value.  But since `0` **is** already a `Numeric` value (as your `grep` example shows), it is actually a no-op.

Then why doesn't show it?  Well, for the simple reason that `0.Bool` is `False`, and `1.Bool` and `(-1).Bool` are `True`.  So in the `if` statement:

```
say $n if $n.Numeric;
```

`0` will not be shown, because `if` conceptually coerces to `Bool` under the hood.  And this will not fire, because `0.Numeric.Bool` is `False`.

You probably wanted to do

```
say $n if $n ~~ Numeric;
```

**THAT** would test if $n has a `Numeric` value in it.